# Spring 4.0: Resolve Type of GenericDao

Tags: java, spring, generics, spring-mvc, autowired

I updated my Spring MVC environment to Version 4.0.0.RELEASE. After reading this article (https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics), I tried to use the new generics support, to autowire my GenericDAOs.

**Spring 3.2**

In Spring 3.2 environment I created for each DAO instance a separate bean and passed the class as paramameter to constructor. This because as I am aware, it is not possible to resolve a generic type at runtime.

```
@Bean
public GenericDaoImpl<Permission, Integer> permissionDao() {
    return new GenericDaoImpl<Employee, Integer>(Employee.class, sessionFactory); 
}
```

**Spring 4.0.0.RELEASE**

With spring 4.0 I just have to autowire my GenericDAO in Service like:

```
@Autowired private GenericDaoImpl<Employee, Integer> employeeDao;
```

And within GenericDAOImpl:

```
@Repository
public class GenericDaoImpl<T, PK extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T, Serializable> {

        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        private Class<?> genericType;
```

This solution is much easier and does work for most of my DAO methods. But for a few of them I need to know which type my GenericDAO instance has.

```
@Override
public List<T> findAll() {
    return getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM " + getGenericType().getName()).list();
}
```

So I tried to resolve the type with the static methods of `GenericTypeResolver` and `ResolvableType`. But I am not able to resolve the type. Is this still not possible?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

```
private Class<T> getGenericType() {
    return (Class<T>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(GenericDaoImpl.class, GenericDao.class);
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you tried and failed to get working.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. By any chance did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I am still working with the old solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
private Class<T> getGenericType() {
    return (Class<T>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(GenericDaoImpl.class, GenericDao.class);
}
```

Your `GenericDaoImpl` doesn't have a type associated as it is generic, it will not resolve to a proper type.

Instead of passing in the `GenericDaoImpl.class` you should call `getClass()` and pass that in, because you want to know the type of the current instance

```
private Class<T> getGenericType() {
    return (Class<T>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(getClass(), GenericDao.class);
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: I tried it with retrun (Class<T>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArguments(getClass(), GenericDao.class)[0]; --> Because Generic Dao has two type arguments, but always receive null.

Comment: Is there still no solution to resolve a generic type of an object which is created by spring ioc? (Without passing the type over the constructor)